# Uninstall ClickOne application with different versions using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, clickonce

I want to uninstall a application reference(.appref-ms) that have different version using Powershell.

For example there is application reference named [ApplicationName] and there are three different version. I want [ApplicationName] ver 1.0.11 remain installed while 1.0.1 and 1.0.3 will be uninstalled.

```
$InstalledApplicationNotMSI = Get-ChildItem HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall | foreach-object {Get-ItemProperty $_.PsPath}


$UninstallString = $InstalledApplicationNotMSI | ? { $_.displayname -eq "ApplicationName"} | select uninstallstring


cmd /c $UninstallString.UninstallString
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first locate the field where the application version is located. Open `regedit.exe` and navigate to:

```
HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

Then, in the PowerShell script, add an additional filter criterion to the query you're making on this line:

```
$UninstallString = $InstalledApplicationNotMSI | ? { $_.displayname -eq "ApplicationName"} | select uninstallstring
```

For example:

```
$UninstallString = $InstalledApplicationNotMSI | ? { ( $_.displayname -eq "ApplicationName") -and ($_.DisplayVersion - eq "2.0")} | select uninstallstring
```

The above uses the `DisplayVersion` entry under the key to further filter the result to the application you need.